# Angular2 JSONP request and callback

Tags: angular, typescript, request, jsonp

I have to request a third-party WS to get a JSON, and need to use JSONP to prevent the cross-domain error.

The problem is, i got this error in my console :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined at 'myURL...'

The response of my request is this format :

> callback({"mywellformatted": "JSON"});

My code seems good, and i don't understand this error :

```
import { JsonpModule, Jsonp, URLSearchParams, Response } from '@angular/http';

export class MyService {

    constructor(private _jsonp: Jsonp) { }

    search() {
    let myURL: string = "https://my.url/search?someParams....&callback=callback
    return this._jsonp
        .request(myURL)
        .map(response => {
            console.log(response);
            "do what i want with this result"
        })
}
```

Can anyone help me ?
[image]

Comment: There's no evidence that the response is proper indeed, a screenshot from dev tools network tab would help. It is probably supposed to be ...callback=JSONP_CALLBACK

Comment: I already tried to set callback value to JSONP_CALLBACK, but it doesn't change anything.
i upload a screenshot

Comment: If you properly set callback=JSONP_CALLBACK, the jsonp should start with JSONP_CALLBACK({...})